# create a scatter plot from a csv file with categories

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I only just stepped into Python and I'm trying to generate a scatter plot with several categories. I am using the Iris Dataset as a basis, here is what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

iris_data = np.genfromtxt(
    "iris.csv", names=True,
    dtype="float", delimiter=",")

x=iris_data["sepal_length"]
y=iris_data["sepal_width"]
g=iris_data["class"]
plt.scatter(x,y)

plt.show()
```

I don't know how to separate out the classes and plot each one on the same graph.

I am coming from Matlab where all I needed was the 
"gscatter(x,y,g) creates a scatter plot of x and y, grouped by g" to get the job done, but I am finding out that python needs a little more to get the **group by g** part done.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part you're struggling with? Have you looked at the matplotlib documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/):

```
import seaborn as sns, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
sns.scatterplot(x='sepal_length',y='sepal_width',data=iris,hue='species')

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

You can do the same in matplotlib as in the example below as long as your data is organized in a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) DataFrame:

```
for k,g in iris.groupby('species'):
    plt.scatter(g['sepal_length'],g['sepal_width'],label=k)
```